# How to update AspNetCore from 2.2.0 to 2.2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

tldnr: How do I upgrade `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` from `2.2.0` to `2.2.2`? It's disabled in the package manager UI.

---

When I created a testproject I realized that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` was version `2.2.2` (newest version) whereas in my main Api project it was `2.2.0`.

[image: projects dependencies and SDK references]

I could not update it due to

> Implicitly referenced by an SDK. To update the package, update the SDK
>   to which it belongs

[image: nuget manager blocking update of package to 2.2.2]

I do have SDK 2.2.104 installed, which [should contain 2.2.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) (I love how straight forward Microsoft is with its version numbers)

```
C:\Users\matthias>dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.600-preview-009472 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

What's the correct way of updating this all to `2.2.2`? I could set the version number for the package in the `csproj` and it seems to work just fine, but I guess that's not the clean way to go. Why would the UI disable it then.

Project file is from the default template.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Source: https://github.com/matthiaslischka/netcore222updateissue

**UPDATE:**

I have now added `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` `2.2.2` to the csproj like ESG suggested and now I get this strange view:

[image: Nuget manager shows different versions for the same package]

I've inspected the compiled DLLs with [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) and it seems to still be 2.2.0.0
[image: ilspy show version 2.2.0.0]

Comment: Check the [docs: implicit version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implicit-versioning), its pretty well documented. Basically: When omitting the `Version` attribute from `PackageReference`, it will always use the latest installed on the **BUILD SYSTEM** (assuming you do not manually specify a specific version of a specific package in your **web apps** csproj). Idea behind is to automatically apply security fixes on a rebuild (for self-contained apps or a roll-forward on portable apps)

Comment: So? Why does it not take `2.2.2` then? I have SDK `2.2.104` installed [what is 2.2.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2). I added the csproj xml and a link to the source. But it's only the default template anyway.

Comment: Did you ever end up resolving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted this in response to Andy's GitHub bug, but re-posting it here for further reach:

If you are using .NET Core, the only thing you need to do to update to the patch is install the latest patched runtime on the machine running the app (i.e. your servers, dev boxes, etc.).

.NET Core applications **automatically** roll forward to the highest patch version associated with the major/minor pair you target. This behavior can be disabled using [a setting in `[appname].runtimeconfig.json`](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/92072fd9ea03740ea317b631d3894ff3c5d0854d/Documentation/design-docs/roll-forward-on-no-candidate-fx.md) but we **strongly recommend** you keep it to ensure you always run on the most up-to-date runtime (with all released security fixes).

While we do recommend you **run** on the latest patch, we recommend you **do not** update your app to target later patch versions as your app will *fail to start* if that patch doesn't exist on the target machine. Patches shouldn't be introducing APIs that you need to update to depend upon so there's no need to update the package reference.

Comment: So if I have SDK 2.2.401 and runtime 2.2.6 then I should be able to update AspNetCore.App from 2.2.0 to <anything>? Because I can't - it says blocked. This being the first action I'm trying to do in a new Web Application.

Comment: It's blocked because you don't have to update :). At runtime, you'll run on version 2.2.6. Patches don't introduce new API or features, so there's nothing to change in your code. You should write your code targeting the 2.2.0 version and let it run on the latest runtime. NuGet is preventing the update because it's not necessary to update.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the 2.2.2 .Net core SDK, you force the version of ASP.Net by specifying the `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` in your `csproj`.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.2.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Don't understand. Target version in the project is `netcoreapp2.2`, no patch number there: `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>` That's the highest target version according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)

Comment: @Matthias My bad, that was for minor versions, not for patch version. See update.

Comment: Does not change anything. I tested with a default template([source](https://github.com/matthiaslischka/netcore222updateissue)), does not work.

Comment: I've forked your project and applied the change. See screenshots in repo root: https://github.com/EricStG/netcore222updateissue

Comment: See my update in the original post. This seems to just edit the version number that the nuget package manager displays, but not the real version number. This actually confuses me even more...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with 2.2.8, installing the x86 version of the SDK cinched it. Seems unit tests are 32-bit processes?